# ASP.NET Application setting debug="false" in web.config breaks Javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

We have an application that works fine when we have debug="true" in Web.config, when we set this to "false" however the application stops working. It seems as if object inheritance is not working in the javascript (Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method). Has anyone come across this before?

A bit more error detail:

a.beginUpdate() is not a function

Comment: As far as i know there is no relationship between debug="false" and javascript if we are talking about working of the project. I have never come across this before. Does it properly work when in debug true

Answer (score 2):

First off, don't try to debug your javascript in IE 7 or 8.  It's a losing proposition -- you'll only end up scratching your head and swearing about what that error means.   Download a copy of Google Chrome, Firefox with FireBug, or IE9+.  That will show you where the error *really* is.  Start there.

Second, I'd bet it has something to do with UI objects being named differently when sent back to the client, or maybe an element just isn't there for some reason.

Comment: This is outdated. Recent IE debugging tools are great (and yes, I've also used firebug and chrome)

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is what it was...a couple of the controls had the below missing in their constructors. Nice

`ControlName.initializeBase(this)`

Answer (score 2):

I Had the same issue, after checking all the properties, I noticed the `AppPool` didn't have the permissions to read some files in the deploy folder, so I've created a new `Application Pool Connected by a User`, granted privileges and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Not come across this problem, but if you enable script debugging in IE, you can step through your javascript and narrow the problem down. I'd be surprised if javascript in the client was being affected by the app settings on the server, but I could be wrong...